# Column validation for datepicker - end date must be within 2 years of start date

Tags: list, column, validation, settings, datepicker

I have a datepicker. I went into list settings for the start date and set the validation to =Start Date >= today() That works great. Now I want the End Date to be within 2 years of that End Date or before 2021. How would I do that. I tried this =End Date < 2021. That didn't work. It prevented submission of the form. I've been looking but haven't found an answer.

Thanks for your assistance and have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
=AND( [Start Date]>=TODAY(), [End Date]<DATE(2021,1,1), [End Date]<TODAY()+(365*2) )
```

Is dealing with an exact 2 years (leap year, etc.) important?

Answer (score 0):

This will only allow people to use a date that is within 364 days of today.

=[End Date]<=TODAY()+364